# Objects and Classes with Java a flaw with my logic

Tags: java

I've made too classes, `MyDate` class holds someone's birthday and does the logic to get the difference in years between two dates. `Person` holds someone's name and birthday and in it you can check to see if a person is older than another.

in `MyDate` this is how I got the difference in years:

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
        int difference = 0;

        if (this.year > comparedDate.year) {
            difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;

            if (this.month == comparedDate.month && this.day < comparedDate.day
                    || this.month < comparedDate.month) {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        if (comparedDate.year > this.year) {
            difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;

            if (comparedDate.month == this.month && comparedDate.day < this.day
                    || comparedDate.month < this.month) {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        return difference;
    }
```

and in `Person` these are the two relevant methods:

```
 public int age() {
        // you get the current day as follows: 
        //Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
        //Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // January is 0 so we add one
        //Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

        return calendar.differenceInYears(this.birthday);
    }
```

`calendar` is a `new MyDate` that I initiated in the class that holds the current date.

The second method that I'm using checks if a person is older than the other:

```
public boolean olderThan(Person compared) {
        if (this.age() > compared.age()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, the program seems to run fine, but when I test and let the exercise check if the program runs fine it gives me this message :

***FAIL: PersonTest olderThanTest2***

***Person Helga, born 31.12.2009 should be older than Janika, born 1.1.2010***

Comment: `return calendar.differenceInYears(this.birthday);` where is the `compared` person here ?

Comment: You need to change the logic and compare directly both dates: Helga and Janika. It is more intuitive and easier to code. And more efficient: if Helga was born in 2001 and Janika in 2005 you are done.

Comment: Check the pseudo code below

Comment: The Java types `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` both have methods `after` and `before`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code:

param1 date1
param2 date2

```
if (date1.year == date2.year){
    if (date1.month == date2.month){
        return date1.day > date2.day;
    }
    else
        return date1.month > date2.month;
}
else
    return date1.year > date2.year;
```